# Wordpress edit image tag in classic editor

Tags: html, wordpress, image, nextgen-gallery

I'm trying to make some images link to pages in wordpress.
I've added the images, but can't find the `<img>` tag so I can change it to a `<a>` tag.
In the Visual editor aswell as the Classic editor the images show up as actual images.

I have Nextgen installed aswell, but that didn't seem to let me use 1 single image as the link to an album (it sortoff does, but that image is too smal + has weird borders).

Does anyone know how to get to the `<img>` tag, or maybe a better method to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
Apparently after going into the Classic editor, you have to select "Text" in the top-right.